If X, Y and Z are pairwise independent variables, then are the sum of two, and the remaining one independent?
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4296301/1312809 suggests that the vector and the remaining RV are independent.
The answer below that discusses joint independence.
So which is it? Is there a counter-example showing that the sum can be a function of the third RV?

Suppose you toss a fair penny and a fair dime.  Let $X$ be $1$ if the penny comes up $H$, and $0$ otherwise.  $Y$ the same for the dime, and $Z=1$ if the two coins come up the same and $0$ otherwise.
Then $X,Y,Z$ are pairwise independent.  But knowing that $X+Y=2$ tells you that $Z=1$.  Indeed, $X+Y$ determines $Z$ uniquely in all cases.
